# magento android APP for customers

Tags: android, magento

I'm developing an android app to work with magento and I wanted to have option to login for customers and they can add item to cart, view what they have in cart and buy stuff but all I could find was something that you can view all customers, view all orders, couldn't find how to make login for customers and how they could add items to cart and buy that.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Seriously this sounds like about 100 questions... where have you started on this?

Comment: The main problem is that whatever I try to look for, I can find only option to login for API user (I can't find customer authentication).
I want to have app that user opens, logs in to his account and from there he can add stuff to cart, remove it, etc).

Comment: You might wanna try using http://magento.stackexchange.com/ - you may get some better advice

Answer (score 0):

in order to get customer's cart detail using rest api first get customer token using  api "POST /V1/integration/customer/token".

curl  -X POST  "http://example.com/rest/V1/integration/customer/token"

-H "Content-Type: application/json"
-d '{"username":"username","password": "password"}'

This will return a token. You can use this token in header in order to access customer resources

Like for cart details

Let Token is XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

curl -X GET "http://domainname.com/rest/V1/carts/mine"\
-H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"